# Problems with deallocating memory in C++ (delete operator)

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, free, dynamic-arrays, delete-operator

I'm  confused with the delete[] operators in C++. I know it's purpose to deallocate the dynamic memory (heap). But I have tried this code below and found some troubles:

```
int *dynArrOne = new int[10];
int *dynArrTwo = nullptr;
```

So it's creating 10 new address in heap from pointer **dynArrOne** in stack. Then I wrote:

```
int *dynArrOne = new int[10];
int *dynArrTwo = dynArrOne;
```

Therefore **dynArrTwo** and **dynArrOne** now pointing to same address in heap. The memory in heap will be deallocated if I write: `delete [] dynArrOne;`. And trouble is that I couldn't deallocated the memory in heap via **dynArrTwo**: `delete [] dynArrTwo`. I mean, why did it happen? Why I can't deallocate memory in heap via **dynArrTwo**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a *copy* of a pointer, then that's *all* you are doing - you are *not* making a copy of the memory that is pointed-to.

So, your statement `int *dynArrTwo = dynArrOne;` is simply duplicating the *address* stored in the RHS pointer. When the memory pointed to by *either* variable is released with the `delete[]` operation, then both pointers will become invalid.

Think of it this way: I could write down the address of a house (the *same* address, *same* house) on two pieces of paper, and give one piece of paper each to two *different* demolition men. If the first of these demolition guys goes and knocks down the house, then the second one can't, later, go do the same - can he?

Comment: Okay, tell me if I'm wrong: "Let's define `dynArrOne[2]=5;` for example. And make the dynArrTwo also pointing to same address that dynArrOne pointed. Therefore the output for `dynArrTwo[2]` also 5. To prove that dynArrOne and dynArrTwo is pointing to same address is by modify the value in dynArrTwo. Say, `dynArrTwo[2] = 7` and it turns out that `dynArrOne[2]` is also 7. Therefore it's true that they are pointing to same address. When I'm say `delete[] dynArrTwo`, it's still valid to say `dynArrTwo[2]` nor `dynArrOne[2]`, no change at all. I have tried this, so did I missed some concept?"

Comment: @RaihansyahHarahap OK! What you have here is *undefined behaviour* - even though your program has 'officially' freed the memory with the `delete[]` call, that memory does still (in your case) exist. As it hasn't (yet) been modified by any other code, you are seeing the 'old' values - but you can ***never*** rely on this happening.